# What does "undefined method for #" mean in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I'm in trouble with `delayed_jobs` in production. I got `undefined method SOMEMETHOD for #` error and what I want to understand is what is the meaning of `for #`. It's neither a `Fixnum`, nor a `Class`. I wonder what it is.

My trace:

```
undefined method `build_integration_profiles_second_part_without_delay' for #
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:206:in `method_missing'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/performable_method.rb:26:in `perform'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:105:in `block in invoke_job'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rollbar-0.12.20/lib/rollbar/delayed_job.rb:9:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rollbar-0.12.20/lib/rollbar/delayed_job.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in '
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in add'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `block in add'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:102:in `invoke_job'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:207:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/home/tristan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
/home/tristan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `call'
/home/tristan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:207:in `block in run'
/home/tristan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:206:in `run'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:274:in `block in reserve_and_run_one_job'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:274:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:190:in `block in work_off'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:189:in `times'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:189:in `work_off'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:154:in `block (4 levels) in start'
/home/tristan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:153:in `block (3 levels) in start'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:152:in `block (2 levels) in start'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:151:in `loop'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:151:in `block in start'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in '
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in add'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `block in add'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:150:in `start'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:104:in `run'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:92:in `block in run_process'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:255:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:255:in `block in start_proc'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:82:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:82:in `call_as_daemon'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:259:in `start_proc'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:296:in `start'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:159:in `block (2 levels) in start_all'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:158:in `fork'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:158:in `block in start_all'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:157:in `each'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:157:in `start_all'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/controller.rb:80:in `run'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:197:in `block in run_proc'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `call'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `catch_exceptions'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:196:in `run_proc'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:90:in `run_process'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:83:in `block in daemonize'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:81:in `times'
/home/tristan/joggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:81:in `daemonize'
bin/delayed_job:5:in `
```

UPDATED: 
I've added my trace because it happened again. Last time, I figured out what the problem is. `Delayed_job`s wasn't displaying the whole thing and as it turns out to be, it was a Shopify `ActiveResource` instance. This time, it's a different method and I really don't know what the `#` is. Not sure which class this was on.

Comment: When you're reporting errors, it almost always helps to show the line of source code that generated it. The stack trace is immensely helpful in finding out where things went wrong. Otherwise, if you don't specify that, it's a guessing game.

Comment: Agreed. I will make sure to include for next time!

Comment: Doesn't the error message really look like `undefined method SOMEMETHOD for #<SomeModel:0x...>`?

Comment: Not in delayed job does it

Comment: I agree with @muistooshort--I think your error message has a class name but it is getting swallowed by something (did you copy the trace from a web page?)

Comment: I copied it from delayed_job's web interface